# Pegar os dados do mysql e usar no MapsFragment em Android

Tags: php, android, banco-de-dados, google-maps

Minha parte de php acredito que está funcionando. Não sei como pegar estes dados para o Android. Como eu posso fazer?
Preciso passar os dados nome,mensagem,lat,long para alguma variável no android.

Parte em Php:

```
    $sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM mensagem 
     INNER JOIN usuarios ON mensagem.idUsuarios = usuarios.idUsuarios

");

foreach ($sql as $value) {
//$sql = $value['mensagem'];
echo $value['nome']; 
echo "<br>";
echo $value['mensagem'];
echo "<br>";
echo $value['lat'];
echo "<br>";
echo $value['long'];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Parte em Android:

```
package mundosenai.mundosenai.com.mundosenai;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getMapAsync(this);
}

double lat;
double longi;
String mensagem;
String nome;





@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng MinhaLocalizacao = new LatLng(lat, longi);



    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MinhaLocalizacao, 3));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras distintas que é possível resolver seu problema, retornando mesmo resultado usando JSON ou XML. A princípio é preciso estruturar as informações retornadas do PHP de uma forma compacta uma destas formas. Vou mostrar abaixo como seria utilizando JSON.

## JSON

O JSON (*JavaScript Object Notation*) é um modelo para armazenamento e transmissão de informações no formato texto.

A partir do PHP versão 5.2 é possível transformar um `Array` em um JSON, com as funções `json_encode` e `json_decode` e nos prevenir a possíveis erros com o `json_last_error`.

> O JSON é uma estrutura para representação dados em JavaScript

- `json_decode` — Decodifica uma string JSON
- `json_encode` — Retorna a representação JSON de um valor
- `json_last_error_msg` — Retorna uma string contento a mensagem de erro da  - ultima chamada de json_encode() ou json_decode()
- `json_last_error` — Retorna o último erro ocorrido

#### Exemplo

```
{"latitude": -25.6355281, "longitude": 45.8824533}
```

Segundo passo, seria o consumo do JSON com Android utilizando HTTP, que também existem várias ferramentas para seu caso. Aqui [neste artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/consumindo-dados-de-um-web-service-com-android/33717), tem um bom exemplo de como você pode fazer isso.

#### Detalhes

- [Trabalhando com JSON em PHP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-php/26716)
- [JavaScript Object Notation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.json.php)
- [JSON Example](http://json.org/example.html)
- [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)
- [Consumindo JSON em aplicações Android](http://www.devmedia.com.br/consumindo-json-em-aplicacoes-android/27589)

Comment: Eu sou novato no php e android, poderia me mostrar como eu faço isso?

Comment: @MarcosKropp eu coloquei algumas referências para você entender melhor. Dê uma lida neste artigo, que você vai aprender um pouco mais: http://mariohercules.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/utilizando-mysql-e-php-para-gerar-json.html

Comment: @MarcosKropp já estamos em contato! As dúvidas podem ser tiradas por aqui mesmo. E eu também estou no meu job, só posso responder quando sobra algum tempinho.

Comment: Assim, eu não sei como fazer o código, do jeito que eu fiz consigo receber os dados do Banco de Dados, mas não sei como retorna-lo para o Android, sendo que preciso retornar estes dados para a MapsFragment que é toda diferente das outras.